# make API on the server available only for me

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

There are public API on the server that consists of url requests. I want this API will be available only for me. What can I do for that? I use IOS and this will be Iphone app.

Answer (score 1):

When you send request to your server, in the body of your request you can send some key, that only you application and your server knows.

To protect your app from reverse engineering: you could collect your string in multiple strings, and then merge them in one string. For example, if you have string "ios", you can create three string "i" "o" "s" and then merge them in one in your urlrequest. In this case reverse engineering and strings on the binary don't work.

Comment: And it should be encoded in some form, or somebody will reverse engineer it very quickly by running `strings` on the binary.

Comment: thanks for advice. H2CO3 do you know some code examples how to  encode this urlrequest string that contains some key?

Comment: @stackoverflow04 base85 and XORing is a common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this scneario it is slower but it is good.

1. Server will send challenge phrase
2. iPhone will send the phrase encrypted with certain key.
3. server will record this session as valid for 30 minutes.
4. iPhone send the encrypted challenge phrase with each request it will send to the
   server.